# Showing the limit of given function does not exist

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Given $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mid f(x)\mid\geq M$ for some $M > 0$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I need to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ does not exist.

My try :

Assume limit exist, say L.

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt[3]{x}}=\frac{\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt[3]{x}}=L$

$\Rightarrow$  $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=L.\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt[3]{x}=0$ , contradiction to the fact that $\mid f(x)\mid \geq M, \forall x$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{s(x)}{g(x)}$ might exist irrespective of the quantity $\frac{\lim_{x\to0}s(x)}{\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)}$ to exist or make sense syntactically (but then again, making sense syntactically seems not to be that fashionable anymore). In point of fact, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt[3]x}$ can only exist in $\Bbb R$ if $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ (but this condition is not sufficient).

Comment: So my solution is wrong?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @Gae.S., I disagree. The OP's proof is basically correct. It uses the limit theorem $\lim(FG)=(\lim F)(\lim G)$ with $F(x)=f(x)/\sqrt[3]x$ and $G(x)=\sqrt[3]x$.  The only thing lacking, in my opinion, is a proof from first principles that $|f(x)|\ge M\gt0$ for all $x$ prevents $\lim f(x)=0$.

Comment: Ok, A+ to him, then, what do I care.

Comment: @BarryCipra I agree that the argument is correct. The proof for the contradiction you ask for can probably be expected to be known (something like "convergence preserves inequalities" is usually covered).

Comment: Big mistake. The original proof is not correct. You can push over the limit only when the limit of the denominator is not zero.

Comment: On closer examination, the expression $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\over\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt[3]x$ is inappropriate here. That is, the limit theorem $\lim(F/G)=(\lim F)/(\lim G)$ holds only when $\lim G\not=0$, which is not the case for $G(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ as $x\to0$. But remove it and everything else is OK.

Comment: @BarryCipra That of course is true, but is the only error in the argument. A fact I also overlooked.

Comment: Or shortened: You can’t use an argument for the quotient, but you can use one for the product.

Comment: @BarryCipra Oh.. thanks to point out that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing a set of comments below the OP, the only mistake in your proof is in the problematic expression $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\over\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt[3]x$, which is of the utterly meaningless form $\text{possibly undefined}\over 0$. But it's an expression you don't need at all; it's enough to say $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)\over\sqrt[3]x}=L$. That equation is all it takes to express the assumption that the limit, call it $L$, exists.  As for the denouement, what you've written is basically correct, but it might be clearer to write it as

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\left({f(x)\over\sqrt[3]x}\sqrt[3]x\right)=\left(\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)\over\sqrt[3]x}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt[3]x\right)=L\cdot0=0$$

The take home message here, in terms of learning to write proofs, is to look at each and every assertion you make and ask yourself if it's both meaningful and true. If an assertion fails on either criterion, you then need to ask yourself what's it doing there? In this case, the answer is Nothing!

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove this rigorously, you need to use the definition or prove by contradiction. Suppose that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^{1/3}}=l.$$

Take $\epsilon =1$,  $\exists\delta>0$, for all $x$, such that $0<|x|<\delta \Rightarrow |\frac{f(x)}{x^{1/3}}-l|<\epsilon$. Using triangle inequality, we have $|f(x)|<|x^{1/3}|\cdot (|l|+1)$. Now take $x=\min \{\delta/2, \frac{M^3}{(|l|+1)^3}\}$ and got a contradiction.